# How to find the stationary points of a function with trigonometric terms?

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider the function
>   $$f(x,y) = \sin(x)+\sin(y)+\sin(x+y)$$
>   for $0\le x,y \le 2\pi$.

I calculated the gradient vector:

$$\nabla f(x,y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)x\\
\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)y
\end{bmatrix}$$

But how can I determine the zeroes of $\nabla f(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Wrong gradient you get...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get $$f_x=\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)=0$$ and $$f_y=\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)=0$$
Now use $$\cos(x)+\cos(y)=2 \cos \left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \cos
   \left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$
It is $$\cos(x+\frac{y}{2})\cos(y/2)=0$$ etc.
and $$2 \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+y\right)=0$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just set $f_x=f_y$ and cancel out $\cos(x+y)$ to get $\cos (x) = \cos(y)$, which means $y = x$ or $y = 2\pi - x$?

Comment: I like the product form!

Answer (score 1):

Your gradient vector is not correct.$$\nabla f(x,y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)x\\
\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)y
\end{bmatrix}$$

should have been 
$$\nabla f(x,y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)\\
\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)
\end{bmatrix}$$

You need to solve $$\cos(x)+\cos(x+y)=0, \cos(y)+\cos(x+y)=0$$

Note that  $$\cos (\pi \pm x)= - \cos(x)$$ which makes your solution simple to find.